# Errors when trying to generate an XSD from a C# class with xsd.exe .NET utility

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, xsd, xsd.exe

I am trying to generate an XSD from a C# object but I get errors pertaining to the DLL file that my class is using.

My command parameters are:

**Directory of the program:** "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\xsd.exe"

**DLL file:** "C:\Working\Products\WebConvey\Components\Server.Net\WebConvey.Data\bin\x86\Debug\WebConvey.Data.dll"

**Output file directory:** 
"C:\Working\Products\"

**Class type:** "
VerboseLoan"

> These are the errors:

[CMD Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39cxj.png)

> And here is the class its complaining about:

[initialRequest_1-1.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcW3p.png)

If anyone can just tell me where to begin debugging, that would be great :)

Comment: The problem is in the `messageBody` class, which you haven't posted. Also please post code, rather than images.

Comment: However, it looks like you have two classes called `messageBody` in different namespaces. You can't have two XSD elements with the same name in the same namespace, so you'll need to call one of those elements something different to `messageBody`. Hence the message "*Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type*"

Comment: The code is a bit length thats why I didn't want to add it. But thanks.

Comment: This is why we encourage askers to reduce the problem to a [mcve], and post that.